# Count unique number of instances in dataframe by specified index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, sum, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe, `sega_df`:

```
    Character  Month    Code
    Sonic      18-Jan   P008924
    Shadow     18-Jan   P007869
    Sonic      18-Feb   P007811
    Sonic      18-Feb   P008639
    Sonic      18-Mar   P008242
    Sonic      18-Mar   P007823
    Sonic      18-Mar   P007823
    Sonic      18-Mar   P008380
    Sonic      18-Apr   P008637
    Shadow     18-Apr   P008266
```

In my desired output, I would like to count the number of unique codes per month per character. Which means, for example, for `Sonic`, for the month of March, I would like to see a total of 3 rather than 4 (ignoring how `P007823` occurs twice, and there are three codes for the month of March for him). My desired output is:

```
                       Jan 18  Feb 18  Mar 18  Apr 18
Character                                     
Sonic                  1.0     2.0     3.0    1.0
Shadow                 1.0     0.0     0.0    1.0
```

I have attempted `.count()` and `.unstack()`, and thought about using `.sum()` at the end. My code thus far is:

```
sega_pivot = sega_df.groupby(['Character','Month']).count().unstack()
```

Answer (score 0):

***Option 1***
**`drop_duplicates`** then use your method:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('Code').groupby(['Character', 'Month']).count().unstack().fillna(0)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()

Month      18-Apr  18-Feb  18-Jan  18-Mar
Character
Shadow        1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
Sonic         1.0     2.0     1.0     3.0
```

***Option 2***
**`pivot_table`** with **`aggfunc`** and **`unique`**

```
df.pivot_table(index='Character', columns='Month', values='Code', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))

Month      18-Apr  18-Feb  18-Jan  18-Mar
Character
Shadow        1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
Sonic         1.0     2.0     1.0     3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution from `crosstab`

```
df=df.drop_duplicates(['Character','Code'])
pd.crosstab(df.Character,df.Month)
Out[166]: 
Month      18-Apr  18-Feb  18-Jan  18-Mar
Character                                
Shadow          1       0       1       0
Sonic           1       2       1       3
```